# How to get queryset as result for join Query using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have following table and relationship between them.

```
class Customer(models.Model):    
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, db_index=True)    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,null=True)

class B(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, to_field="customer_id", db_column="customer_id")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False, default="pending")

class C(models.Model):    
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, to_field="customer_id", db_column="customer_id")
    engagement_rate = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Now , I want to create pagination Api to fetch each row from table 
Customer and it's related detail from table B and C. I have set foriegn key between this tables. I have read this [blog](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/) to do join query , but did not able to apply for my case.

please any one can suggest me way around it to get this data in single db call .

Comment: What exactly are u trying to join ? what is the goal here ? I think the blog you've looked is old and there r other ways to manipulate querys

Comment: try using .anotate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be possible to fetch all this data in a single query. Well a single query to the server that is. But it's a single ORM query.

```
Customer.objects.prefetch_related('c','b').filter(somecondition)
```

If you could use select_related it would be one SQL query but because the foreign key relations are traversed in reverse you need to use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/)

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to
>   prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
>   using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
>   relationships that are supported by select_related

This is still only three queries.

If you are really really keen on doing this in a single SQL query. `Customer.objects.raw()` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for answer . I am getting this exception `Cannot find 'b' on Customer object, 'b' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`

Comment: I actually created the model and tried the query. I bet your real model isn't name B and C :-)

Comment: you are right , real model have diff names. I have tried with my real model names. but not working . Any way you gave me direction , i will try to find way around it

Comment: So what happened in the end?

Comment: I used `Customer.objects.raw()` . And it solved my problem. @e4c5

Comment: I'm also a big fan of raw. But we might have got an ORM query working if you had posted the error., but as they say all's well that ends well :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Customer.objects.prefetch_related('b_set', 'c_set').filter(condition)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single call, but you can certainly do it in two or three with `prefetch_related`.

```
A.objects.all().prefetch_related('B', 'C')
```